# XSLT to remove the last repeating empty segment

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml is looking like this

```
<a>
 <b>b</b>
 <c>
    <d>
     <d1></d1>
     <d2></d2>
    </d>
    <d>
     <d1>1</d1>
     <d2>2</d2>
    </d>    
    <d>
     <d1>3</d1>
     <d2>4</d2>
    </d>
    <d>
     <d1></d1>
     <d2></d2>
    </d>    
 </c>
 
 </a>
```

And I want the out put as keeping the first empty segment(here `<d> <d1></d1> <d2></d2> </d>`)  as it is and remove the last empty segment (`<d> <d1></d1> <d2></d2>  </d>`) as follows

```
<a>
 <b>b</b>
 <c>
    <d>
     <d1></d1>
     <d2></d2>
    </d>
    <d>
     <d1>1</d1>
     <d2>2</d2>
    </d>    
    <d>
     <d1>3</d1>
     <d2>4</d2>
    </d>

 </c>
 
 </a>
```

I have tried the following xsl, but the out put is like this

```
 <a>
 <b>b</b>
 <c>
    <d/>
    <d>
     <d1>1</d1>
     <d2>2</d2>
    </d>    
    <d>
     <d1>3</d1>
     <d2>4</d2>
    </d>

 </c>
 
 </a>
```

I need the empty child tags of first empty segment in the output. Any solution on the xsl is much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not[last()]]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[not[last()]]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[last()][normalize-space() = '']"/>   
    <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's a rather vague requirement. If it is applied across the board, then why is the first  `d2` element not removed? It is the last empty element inside the first `d`.

Comment: Your question as stated could mean any of the following: (a) you want to remove the last segment if it is empty, (b) you want to remove the last segment that is empty, (c) if there is more than one segment that is empty, you want to remove the last one. In addition, you haven't defined what you mean by "segment" and "empty". You really need to state your requirements with more precision.

Comment: @MichaelKay , I have updated the question, here the segment I meant is 'd' segment which is a child of 'c'. Empty means all child segments are empty. Thanks

Comment: It's still a very inadequate specification. We know what output you want from this one sample input, but we need to understand what output you want from ANY input.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 <xsl:template match="c/d[not(*[.!= ''])][last()]"/>
```

to remove the last `d` child of `c` that has only empty children. That would however remove such a `d` element if there is only one such elements (i.e. `last()` is 1), so perhaps you rather want

```
 <xsl:template match="c/d[not(*[.!= ''])][position() > 1 and position() = last()]"/>
```

All that together of course with the identity transformation set up, so declaratively as `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3 or for previous versions of XSLT (1, 2) by setting up the template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got working solution for this. Thanks everyone tried to help.

````
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match and keep the first d -->
  <xsl:template match="c/d[position() = 1]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match and remove the last empty d -->
  <xsl:template match="c/d[position() = last()][normalize-space() = '']"/> ```
````

Comment: you dont need the one that keeps the 1st. You basically just want to remove the last.